# ghidra-python: create struct with big endian field

Tags: python, ghidra

Using ghidra's python scripting engine, I'd like to create a struct which contains a big endian, unsigned integer. This field is always big endian, no matter what the endainess of the binary CPU is.

My first attempt:

```
def uint32b():
    dt = UnsignedIntegerDataType()
    for s in dt.getSettingsDefinitions():
        if isinstance(s, EndianSettingsDefinition):
            s.setBigEndian(dt.getDefaultSettings(), False)
    return dt
```

However, when the struct is applied to data, I'm still seeing a little-endian value. The field's "Default Settings -> Endian"  still set to "Default".

[image: default settings]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following script shows hows to create a structure and set its field to Big Endian   byte order using the Ghidra Python API.

```
from ghidra.program.model.data import DataTypeConflictHandler
from ghidra.program.model.data import EndianSettingsDefinition
from ghidra.app.util.cparser.C import CParser


mystruct_txt = """
struct mystruct{
    uint32_t field1; 
    uint32_t field2;
};"""

# Get Data Type Manager
data_type_manager = currentProgram.getDataTypeManager()

# Create CParser
parser = CParser(data_type_manager)

# Parse structure
parsed_datatype = parser.parse(mystruct_txt)

# Add parsed type to data type manager
datatype = data_type_manager.addDataType(parsed_datatype, DataTypeConflictHandler.DEFAULT_HANDLER)

# Extract the first structure member i.e. mystruct.field1
field1 = datatype.components[0]

# Get Default Settings
field1_settings = field1.getDefaultSettings()

# Set endianess to big
field1_settings.setLong('endian', EndianSettingsDefinition.BIG)
```

If you have already created the structure earlier (using the editor or otherwise) you can omit the part where the structure is created and use [`getDataType`](https://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/api/ghidra/program/database/data/DataTypeManagerDB.html#getDataType(java.lang.String)) to obtain it from the `DataTypeManagerDB` as shown below.

```
datatype = data_type_manager.getDataType("/mystruct")
field1 = datatype.components[0]
field1_settings = field1.getDefaultSettings()
field1_settings.setLong('endian', EndianSettingsDefinition.BIG)
```

After applying the structure to a piece data, you can right click  on the field -> Data -> Default Settings and check that the default endianness is indeed Big Endian.

[image]